# Flash Permissions

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I have a situation wherein I have to keep the size of my flash swf smaller than 215X130 pixel. However, I want to use Microphone, so the permission dialog needs an area at least 215X130.

Could you guys give me some ideas to workaround this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an ExternalInterface-call to a javascript function to resize the flash window before the microphone check, and then resize it back after the user accepts. Or you could use some creative js/css to clip the full size of the banner until you need to accept, then clip it again afterwards (that way the flash file would "expand" over the site instead of taking more space).

Comment: The fact that there's a size restriction implies that the OP has no control over the page it is being embedded on.

Comment: You also don't really need control over the site to do this - if you can send the site owner a javascript snippet instead of a swf file, you should be able to implement any of these fixes quite easily.

Comment: @JonatahHedborg Bit of a restriction if this is an ad running on NineMSN or something.

Comment: Most ad servers will accept a javascript tag. But then you are in the realm of rich media ads, and that's a whole different can of worms.

Comment: Tell me about it, rich media is 50% of what I do at work.. If what we're discussing is the case then @Joy should try and get a placement bought out that accepts an expanding ad.

Comment: Actually, this would be place on my webpage only and not on any third party website. I am trying some DOM manipulations using JavaScript but no help so far.

Comment: @Joy I would put one div inside another div, and then the swf at the deepest level. In the top div I would try putting overflow:visible and width/height to the contracted size, and in the other div set the clip-property to only show the "contracted" area. Then change the clip property when you want to see the whole flash file.